# Can you use a Hero Point more than once for a particular purpose in a round?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

In 2E, you couldn't use a Hero Point more than once in a round for the same purpose.

> Unless otherwise noted, spending a hero point is a reaction, taking no
>   time. You can spend as many hero points as you have, **but only one hero
>   point on any given benefit per round**. You can spend hero points for any
>   of the following things.

So you could use a Hero Point to buy off Fatigue and one to Improve Roll, but you couldn't use a Hero Point to Improve Roll on your attack roll and then use it to Improve Roll on the Toughness save when you find out that The Trap has that name because his outfit manifests beartraps when struck.

I had thought that 3E had the same thing, but that line is missing.

> Unless otherwise noted, spending a hero point is a reaction, taking no time, and you can spend as many hero points as you have. You can spend hero points for any of the following:

Can I get a confirmation that that sentence does not show up somewhere else in the core book, errata, or the Deluxe Anniversary edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have personally just checked two sources.

The 3E book DC Adventure's Heroes Handbook (the first version of M&M 3E to see print) has the text as you quoted on page 21.

The [Deluxe Mutants and Masterminds Hero's Handbook (3E)](http://drivethrurpg.com/product/116671/Mutants--Masterminds-Deluxe-Heros-Handbook) made some changes to the 'original' 3E book (which, itself, made minor changes to the DC Adventures book).  That said, on page 20 it has the same text.

Thus, according to the most up-to-date print/PDF version of the rules, the rule is as printed: you can use as many as you like per round, and you can spend all of them on the same thing if you like.

I have checked the Errata threads at the old Atomic Think Tank, and glanced at the newer ones on Ronin Army.  Both of those turn up no errata pertaining to this rule.

Therefore, it seems that **in 3E you can use multiple hero points for the same effect each round**.

As with any RPG, **this is ultimately up to your GM**.  If they say "no", the answer is "no", no matter what the book says.